# Is it possible to avoid the possibility of opening the camera when requesting a file from the phone?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm making an app with Xamarin and Visual Studio 17.5.3 (build 15) for MacOS. It is for iOS 16.3. In a WebView, when I try to upload a file from the iPhone, three possibilities open up:

- Photo Library
- Camera
- Choose File

Is it possible to prevent the "Camera" option from appearing? In other words, only the options appear

- Photo Library
- Choose File

Thanks.

Comment: You can write the `WKWebViewRender` to control the camera permission. Here is the sample you can refer to [How to fix double permission popup in xamarin ios web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167987/how-to-fix-double-permission-popup-in-xamarin-ios)